# Animated Pie Bubbles dimple data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I working with `dimple.js` Pie Bubbles chart but and I set data for the chart but chart doesn't work properly.I don't know what  is the problem with my data. Sorry because of my silly question I am new in `d3.js` and `dimple.js` 
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/dimple.js"></script>
<script>
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
        // Define all the axes
        data = [
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) },
            { "Distribution" : (Math.random() * 100), "Price" : (Math.random() * 100), "Unit Sales" : (Math.random() * 100) , "Sales Value" : (Math.random() * 100) }
        ];
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 495, 330);
        var xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Distribution");
        var yAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Price");
        var segments = myChart.addMeasureAxis("p", "Unit Sales");
        var size = myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Sales Value");
        var ring = myChart.addSeries(["Price Tier", "Channel"], dimple.plot.pie);
        var pie = myChart.addSeries(["Price Tier", "Owner"], dimple.plot.pie);

        // Zoom in the axis bounds
        xAxis.overrideMin = 40;
        xAxis.overrideMax = 70;
        yAxis.overrideMax = 150;

        // Set the maximum radius for the bubbles
        ring.radius = 75;
        pie.radius = 75;

        // Create fixed 10px ring with a 5px
        // margin (negative sizes are calculated inwards)
        ring.innerRadius = "-10px";
        pie.outerRadius = "-15px";

        // Draw averages for the pie and ring
        ring.aggregate = dimple.aggregateMethod.avg;
        pie.aggregate = dimple.aggregateMethod.avg;

        // Animate by date
        myChart.setStoryboard("Date");
        myChart.draw();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a date field in your data.

The line:

```
myChart.setStoryboard("Date");
```

Iterates the distinct values in the date field, you either need to change the name to something in your data or add a field called Date.